# JS variable inside handlbars script

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have js variable name "reservationUrl", I would like to use this variable inside handlebars script.

```
<script id="reservation-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each this}}
            <a href="'+reservationUrl+'" class="viewReservationLink" >View 
            </a>
        {{/each}}
      </script>
```

any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use it in handlebars brackets and then you're good to go

```
<script id="reservation-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each this}}
    <a href="{{reservationUrl}}" class="viewReservationLink" >View</a>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

If you want to replace the contents of the template itself with arbitrary variable, you should proably pass it to the template on render time instead. That's what templating engines are for, rendering templates with variables, right? :)